# how to stop music using mediaplyer when i home button is pressed ion android

Tags: android, android-layout

h i am  doing one here i need to display some images,at the same time i need to play that images relted sound.using mediaplyer i did that one its plyaing good but my prblm is in middle of the app if i click home button thatn time also music still playing.but i need to stop music when the user click home button, i treied using on pause().but its not working any one help where i did wrong...

```
     GalleryMedia .class:

    public class GalleryMedia extends Activity  implements OnItemSelectedListener{
  public boolean Visibility=true;
     Boolean  loaded = false;
     MediaPlayer intro1, intro2, intro3, intro4, intro5, intro6, intro7, intro8,
        intro9, intro10, intro11, intro12, intro13;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        intro1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.babycooing05);
        intro2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_2);
        intro3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_3);
        intro4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_4);
        intro5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_5);
        intro6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_6);
        intro7 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_7);
        intro8 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_8);
        intro9 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_9);
        intro10 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_10);
        intro11 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_11);
        intro12 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_12);
        intro13 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.starwars);
        Gallery g=(Gallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery);
          g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
          g.setSpacing(10);

          g.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
  } 
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context myContext;
        private int[] myImageIds = {
                R.drawable.bokstavslottet01,
                R.drawable.bokstavslottet02,
                R.drawable.bokstavslottet03,
                R.drawable.bokstavslottet04,
                R.drawable.bokstavslottet05,
                R.drawable.bokstavslottet06,
                R.drawable.bokstavslottet07,
                R.drawable.bokstavslottet08,
                R.drawable.bokstavslottet09,
                R.drawable.bokstavslottet10,
                R.drawable.bokstavslottet11,
                R.drawable.bokstavslottet12,
                R.drawable.bokstavslottet13
    };
             public ImageAdapter(Context c) { this.myContext = c; }
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return this.myImageIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             ImageView i = new ImageView(this.myContext);

                 i.setImageResource(this.myImageIds[position]);




             /* Image should be scaled as width/height are set. */
             i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
             /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
             i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(700, 400));
             Integer e = myImageIds.length;
             Log.i("","length-------"+e);

             return i;
         }

         /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views
          * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */
         public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
                 /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */
             return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));
         }
        }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (position == 0) {

            intro1.start();
            intro1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.babycooing05);
            intro1.start();
        }
        if (position == 1) {
            intro1.stop();
            intro2.start();
            intro2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_2);
            intro2.start();
        }
        if (position == 2) {
            intro2.stop();
            intro3.start();
            intro3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_3);
            intro3.start();
        }
        if (position == 3) {
            intro3.stop();
            intro4.start();
            intro4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_4);
            intro4.start();
        }
        if (position == 4) {
            intro4.stop();
            intro5.start();
            intro5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_5);
            intro5.start();
        }
        if (position == 5) {
            intro5.stop();
            intro6.start();
            intro6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_6);
            intro6.start();
        }
        if (position == 6) {
            intro6.stop();
            intro7.start();
            intro7 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_7);
            intro7.start();
        }
        if (position == 7) {
            intro7.stop();
            intro8.start();
            intro8 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_8);
            intro8.start();
        }
        if (position == 8) {
            intro8.stop();
            intro9.start();
            intro9 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_9);
            intro9.start();
        }
        if (position == 9) {
            intro9.stop();
            intro10.start();
            intro10 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_10);
            intro10.start();
        }
        if (position == 10) {
            intro10.stop();
            intro11.start();
            intro11 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_11);
            intro11.start();
        }
        if (position == 11) {
            intro10.stop();
            intro12.start();
            intro12 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bokstavslottet_12);
            intro12.start();
        }
        if (position == 12) {
            intro12.stop();
            intro13.start();
            intro13 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.starwars);
            intro13.start();
        }
        }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (intro1 != null){
            intro1.stop();
            if (isFinishing()){
                intro1.stop();
                intro1.release();
            }
        }

        if (intro2 != null){
            intro2.stop();
            if (isFinishing()){
                intro2.stop();
                intro2.release();
            }
        }
            if (intro3 != null){
                intro3.stop();
                if (isFinishing()){
                    intro3.stop();
                    intro3.release();
                }
            }
            if (intro4 != null){
                intro4.stop();
                if (isFinishing()){
                    intro4.stop();
                    intro4.release();
                }
            }
            if (intro5 != null){
                intro5.stop();
                if (isFinishing()){
                    intro5.stop();
                    intro5.release();
                }
            }
            if (intro6 != null){
                intro6.stop();
                if (isFinishing()){
                    intro6.stop();
                    intro6.release();
                }
            }
            if (intro7 != null){
                intro7.stop();
                if (isFinishing()){
                    intro7.stop();
                    intro7.release();
                }
            }
            if (intro8 != null){
                intro8.stop();
                if (isFinishing()){
                    intro8.stop();
                    intro8.release();
                }
            }
            if (intro9 != null){
                intro9.stop();
                if (isFinishing()){
                    intro9.stop();
                    intro9.release();
                }
            }
            if (intro10 != null){
                intro10.stop();
                if (isFinishing()){
                    intro10.stop();
                    intro10.release();
                }
            }
            if (intro11 != null){
                intro11.stop();
                if (isFinishing()){
                    intro11.stop();
                    intro11.release();
                }
            }
            if (intro12 != null){
                intro12.stop();
                if (isFinishing()){
                    intro12.stop();
                    intro12.release();
                }
            }
            if (intro13 != null){
                intro13.stop();
                if (isFinishing()){
                    intro13.stop();
                    intro13.release();
                }
            }
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
 }
```

Comment: try calling the `super.onPause()` after you stop the music from playing.

Comment: thaku.but i set super.onpause() into inside onPause().but its nt working

Comment: you're right, but the only question is when is it being called. that should be the last thing that happens in the function

Comment: thaku.it also working now.but another doubt if i have 200 mediaplyer objets then i need to write stop code in 200 objects into onPause() or any alternative is there.

Comment: you should probably have a variable that will hold the mediaPlayer that is currently playing and when you call `inPause()` or `onStop()` you call that variable and shut it down.

Comment: ok.but in my app i need to play 100's of sounds,each sound having one mediaplyer object.its some hardcoding i think.i treid using soundpool but i dont have much idea about that soundpool.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10774/discussion-between-user1105975-and-thepoosh)

Comment: try reading [here](http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html) but, you only need one MedaiPlayer that changes it's source for every one of the images. once it points to backgroundMusic1 and the next time you call it it points to backgroundMusic2

Comment: yes.but i treid that soundpool example but stop fun not working

Comment: ur sended soundpool example if i play 2 song that time how to stop 1 song.here i need backtraking if i move to back that time also i need to play that image related sounds

Comment: what you do when you need to play a different song is to stop playin the one you're already playing, then assign the soundpool to the new song. and start playing it

Comment: ok.but if once i stop song means it stoped.but again back to gallery that time song again not playaing.please if ur free ursended sounpool part2 example.here how to set stop() 1 song to when 2 song playing that time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop your media service in `onStop` method of your Activity. The method **onStop** is always get called when you navigate away from your activity.